# Permission denied while using Files.walk sun.nio.fs.UnixException

Tags: java, file-io, nio

I am trying to prepare a list of all files under /home/ dir.

```
Files.walk(Path.of("/home/"))
                .filter(path -> !Files.isDirectory(path))
                .filter(path -> {
                    try {
                        return !Files.isHidden(path);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .filter(Files::isReadable)
                .forEach(path -> print(path.toString()));
```

After printing a few files it this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/vipin/.dbus
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.fetchNextIfNeeded(FileTreeIterator.java:87)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.hasNext(FileTreeIterator.java:103)
    at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:132)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:497)
    at com.vip.Files.FIleHandling.main(FIleHandling.java:26)
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/vipin/.dbus
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newDirectoryStream(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:432)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.newDirectoryStream(Files.java:474)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:300)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.next(FileTreeWalker.java:373)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.fetchNextIfNeeded(FileTreeIterator.java:83)
    ... 10 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The root cause of this Exception is sun.nio.fs.UnixException due to permission error.

We have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37510979/reading-user-file-system-returns-accessdeniedexception) on this.

My question is: How do we handle such cases when we don't have permission, is there any other API available to check permissions and filter on that?

Comment: Catching the specific exception should solve your problem

Comment: @Jens Catching Exception doesn't look elegant way to solve the problem. Posted this problem to see what others would do in such a case.

Comment: Using `Files.walkFileTree` might give you better control.

Comment: As suggested by Slaw, try to use the following version of Files.walkFileTree: 

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.util.Set,%20int,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor)

Comment: Just to list files, Files.walkFileTree might be a sword where we need a needle. Here we need to provide FileVisitor implementation as well.

Comment: The problem is the `Stream<Path>` returning methods (e.g. `Files.walk`, `Files.find`, etc.) don't allow you to handle errors gracefully and continue on. Note you can extend `SimpleFileVisitor` if you don't need to override all four methods.